# How to get modules' coverage via sonar runner in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

**What we have:**

jenkins 1.6 + SonarQube 4.5.6 + sonnar-runner 2.4 + maven 3.0.5

**Issue Description:**

We use 'Invoke Standalone SonarQube Analysis' in jobs' configuration, and it works fine except that it cannot get test coverage while the analysis just try to parsing the `<base_dir>/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml`. But we have coverage.xml in the modules directory instead, just like `<base_dir>/module1/target/site/cobertura/coverage.xml`

I have tried to set sonar modules, but nothing happened, we still cannot get the coverage data.

Previously, we used sonar-maven-plugin for the analysis, but after we upgrade to SonarQube 4.5.6, we met some issues, like api incompatibility, measure twice, and so we changed to use sonar-runner. sonar-maven-plugin works fine to parsing the modules' coverage.xml.

- How can we retrieve the coverage data in the modules' directory.
- Or how can we merge the modules coverage.xml into one coverage.xml in the root directory for sonar-runner to parse.

Any comment? Thanks very much!

Comment: Using `sonar-runner` on a Maven project can only lead to frustration (no Maven integration, so you'll hit many shortcomings such as this one). Your efforts will be much better spent on using the [Scanner for Maven](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) and fixing any issue you'd hit along the way.

Comment: @Nicolas I guess you mean sonarqube maven builder, in the jobs' configuration with sonarquebe, it's prompted that 'It is no longer recommended to use SonarQube maven builder. It is preferable to set up SonarQube in the build environment and use a standard Jenkins maven target.'  So I guess sonar-runner would be an advanced optiions.

Comment: Nancy the SonarQube post-build action is indeed deprecated, but you should use top-level Maven target with Environment variables as documented [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven). It's the recommended solution for scanning Maven projects on Jenkins.

Comment: @Nicolas Thank you Nicolas, I will have a try to use the top-level Maven target.